# Bypass touch listener events to layout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I have a LinearLayout that contains some other views. I have implemented onTouchListener over it and I want to move it with user gesture. but it has some other views inside it, that have there on click listeners. I have an ImageView and 2 buttons in this layout and these views have there own click listeners. just have a look at layout.

[image]

I can only move my layout when user click on Free space and then start dragging. whereas I want to move layout even though user start dragging from over 
Imageview,btn1 or Btn2.

I know because BTN1,2 and ImageView are set to be clickable that is why they are consuming onTouchListener of LinearLayout. Here is some code of touchListener

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View mView, MotionEvent event) {
        View view = null;

        if(!(mView instanceof  LinearLayout) && !(mView instanceof RelativeLayout)){

            view = (View)(mView.getParent().getParent().getParent());
        }else{
            view = mView;
        }

        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        //final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;

                Log.d("TTP", "X_Delta " + _xDelta + " X " + X + " left margin " + lParams.leftMargin);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int notMoved = X - _xDelta;
                if(notMoved == 0){
                    Log.d("TTP", "ACTION UP ");
                    return  false;
                }


                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                Log.d("TTP", "POINTER UP ");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();


                int mTotalMargin = X - _xDelta;

                boolean isMovingRight = mTotalMargin > 0;


                if ((isMovingRight && mTotalMargin < (getScreenWidth() / 2)) || (!isMovingRight && mTotalMargin > (getScreenWidth() / -2))) {

                    layoutParams.leftMargin = mTotalMargin;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = mTotalMargin * -1;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    Log.d("TTP", "Mov X_Delta " + _xDelta + " X " + X + " getScreenWidth " + getScreenWidth() + " TotalMargin " + mTotalMargin + " " + isMovingRight);

                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.d("TTP", "CANCEL ");

                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**So my question is how can I bypass dragging operation from BTN1,2 and ImageView to LinearLayout regardless of their click events. Please help me I am stuck here **

Comment: Please share the xml layout

Comment: Please tell me what attributes You want to see, I have so much complex layout, and what you are seeing in question is just the case That I am facing

Comment: I want to know are btn1,btn2 and imageView the children of the linearLayout? And what is the status of clickabe in children?

Comment: yes, they are children of LinearLayout as indicated above.

Comment: I think your XML shouldn't have any problem. Please try this custom onTouchListener, https://gist.github.com/e06d07156dcd18a9ad99cab2143555a6

Comment: let me check it in a bit

Comment: dude it is in kotlin and I am working on Java. DOnt know much about it

Comment: This is java https://gist.github.com/2d54879c81a1daf4d61186bd46bd5810

Comment: no I can animate and move my view, I have just posted the demo code. My problem is to bypass button click listeners etc